# how much secure is Java Swing window application

Tags: java, mysql, swing, security

I have made a Java application using Swing. I use a total of 12 classes, 10 forms and one main class. All are packed in a jar with all the necessary libraries and resources. The jar is an executable and is working fine with no issues.

The problem is that it is a database related distributed application.
I have used many `Connection` objects to connect with mysql.
The connection is public. If a hacker or attacker imports my jar to his own project
and try to get the clone of that connection will he be able to hack the database?
If yes, what is the solution and if no, why can't he?

Comment: Did you include the username and password in the files for the connection? You can usually easily decompile the files to look at the source code.

Comment: yes username and password was given at the source code

Comment: then what is the efficient way to give username and password

Comment: An easier attack would be to simply intercept the connection between your code and the database. Absolutely no reverse engineering necessary.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what exactly is in the jar and how you are connecting to the database.

A jar file that just has class-files in it, can be reverse engineered rather easily. This would let a hacker see a great deal of what you have coded, especially things like URL and SQL strings.  You can try to be really clever and build up the strings, but you would probably have to be twice as clever as the hacker to be able to hide things from him.

So, instead of trying to make the jar hack-proof, protect your database.  The public connection should not have very many privileges, and the admin account should not be accessible remotely for the most security.  There are likely more things one should do to secure your database, but I am not a DBA.

Good luck.

Comment: You should also use a tool to obfuscate the code. These generally encode the strings as well and makes the life of a hacker a little bit more difficult.

Comment: @mr-rho I thought of the code obfuscation, and it is a good idea, but some people might think that once the code has been obfuscated, that's enough.

I prefer to code with the expectation that everything will be visible.  So, don't put anything there you don't want seen.  If you then obfuscate, so much the better :)

Comment: i used a class for connection the class has a method taking the database name as string and returning a connection to the caller.a hacker can make a object of the class and call the public method outside of the class and get the connection and execute any query by that.how to make the design to prevent it.

Comment: if i make the method private i can not call the method from a java swing from. writing the database connectivity code again and again whenever  required is very undesired. how to protect the class which has a method which returns a connection to the caller so that a attacker can not make a object of that class

Comment: will obfusate prevent an attacker to create a object of that connect class

Comment: The short answer is "no". Obfuscation doesn't prevent anything, it simply makes the code really "ugly" and hard to read. I've done some research and even private methods can be reverse engineered if you can read byte code. Java is meant to be open. But... you could have two separate programs running (a client and server), completely separate codebases, and they only talk via network protocols.  If the server handled all the actual database connections and the client only talked to the server... the database would be somewhat "safe". Just be careful setting up the client.

Comment: Yes, even if a method is private, do not expect it to not be callable. There are ways to access these methods and even fields.